# Laravel 5.4 with postgresql 10 not working

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I am trying to integrate laravel 5.4 with postgresql. I have changed database.php file and .env but it is always giving "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired" error. It is PDO Exception, I have already installed pdo_pgsql. Please let me know if there is anything missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using PostgreSQL default port number that is 5432. I have recently setup pgadmin4 on a port and thought it will we used for connecting PostgreSQL, this was the mistake.